# How do I set a global variable accessible throughout all routes express/node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, parse-platform

I am getting my feet wet with nodejs and express and I am using Parse API for my backend database.

currently I have an ajax post on page load to one of my routers /getuser, which gets the current user if they are logged in.

I want to know what is the best way to implement this so that the user variable will be accessible across all routes, should I even be doing it this way ?

I basically want to be able to have access to the user throughout the app.

***index.js routes***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
Parse = require('parse').Parse;


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index', { title: 'hello'});

});


//GET USER
router.post('/getuser',function(req,res){
if(req.body.name != null){
username = req.body.name;
loggedIn = true;
res.send(JSON.stringify(username));
}
else{
 loggedIn = false;
}

});

module.exports = router;
```

**scripts.js client side ajax post on page load**

```
   Parse.initialize("xxxxx","xxxxxx");

      var data = {};
      data.name = Parse.User.current().get("username");

            $.ajax({
              url: "/getuser",
              type: "post",
              dataType: "json",
              data: JSON.stringify(data),
              contentType: "application/json",
              cache: false,
              timeout: 5000,
              complete: function() {

              },

              success: function(data) {

                console.log("success" + JSON.stringify(data))

             },

              error: function(data) {
                console.log("error" + JSON.stringify(data))
              },
            });
```

Should I be posting this to my app.js and setting a global variable there ? How would I access that variable across all routes? How would I even post to app.js.

Comment: http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.Vdq0rvmqqko

Comment: I chose not to use passport but rather go with Parse for my user class but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple pattern to share information accross all the routes. In your case it appear you want to share logged in user details with all the routes. For that I would do something like that.

**Save logged in user in to session**

There is `req.session` available if you are using `express-session`. Once your login is done you can save the logged in `uid` into `req.session`

**Inject logged in user to routes**

In your top level routes you can do something like this -

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
   if(req.session.uid){
        //find the user via models , just an example, it should be async
        var user = require('models').findUser(req.session.uid);

        //inject to req object
        req.currentUser = user;

        //all the routes after this will have currentUser in the req
        next();
   } else {
      //no user is logged in
      console.log("Using empty user");

      req.currentUser = null;

      next();
   }
});
```

Thus all the route after this will have `currentUser` depending upon logged in status.

Comment: currently I am loggin in the user client side once they register. This is how the Parse API works. I then pass the currentuser object into one of my routes on page load. Is there a way for me to pass that object in from the client to the server prior to any route requests so that I can set the session variable ? I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: You may have to create a route where you can login the user into the session. Call this route after Parse.login is done. Assign that user id in session. But since ajax request cant set cookie session , you may have to write some token based session scheme.